# Changing Navigation Bar of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying (and failing) to change the navigation bar of the UIImagePickerController .

```
self.pickerController.navigationBar = myCustomBar;
```

doesn't work, since navigationBar is readonly.

I still want to change the buttons (and colors) on the default "cameraControls" bar.
Do you know of any way to do that?
Thanks!

=============

Ok.. Thanks for the quick answers! So let me detail a little bit here... 
For my application I only need the camera feed, and then I want to add my own buttons to a controls bar. I am not interested in photos (not yet anyways). Do you think it's best that I drop the UIImagePicker and just search for something else? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Deepak's most recent answer is the most supported way to do what you're trying to do without a lot of subclassing or new code on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider hiding the original camera controls using the [`showsCameraControls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW22) and set your own controls using a [`cameraOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW19). Both are properties of `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score -1):

You might try searching the subview tree of the UIImagePickerController, finding the camera controls bar and hiding that. Then add a new subview with your controls to replace it.

Comment: If you change anything in the UIImagePickerController aside from using `cameraOverlayView`, Apple will reject the app. They explicitly forbid this in their documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html